# How should multiple parsers for keywords in strings be structured?

Tags: python, parsing, boolean

I'm writing some code that parses strings, often using simple keywords. On parsing, the code performs various actions, such a printing a response, running functions etc. and it keeps track of whether it was able to respond.

I am actually using multiple parsers and have illustrated this in the code shown below.

What would be better ways to structure this code, particularly with a mind to scalability and code compactness? For example, imagine many more parsers being added that operate on principles more complex than simple keyword-spotting.

MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import os
import requests
import subprocess
import sys

def main():

    message = "how are you"
    #message = "ip address"
    #message = "restart"

    triggered = [
        parse_1(message = message),
        parse_2(message = message)
    ]

    if not any(triggered):

        report_help()

def parse_1(
    message = None
    ):

    def keyphrases_text_response(
        message    = None,
        keyphrases = None,
        response   = None
        ):

        if any(pattern in message for pattern in keyphrases):

            print(response)

            return True

        else:

            return False

    triggered = [
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "image"
                        ],
            response   = "http://i.imgur.com/MiqrlTh.jpg"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "sup",
                        "hi"
                        ],
            response   = "sup home bean"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "how are you",
                        "are you well",
                        "status"
                        ],
            response   = "nae bad fam"
        ),
        keyphrases_text_response(
            message    = message,
            keyphrases = [
                        "help",
                        "what can you do"
                        ],
            response   = "I can report my IP address and I can restart my script."
        )
    ]

    if any(triggered):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def parse_2(
    message = None
    ):

    triggered = []

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "IP",
            "I.P.",
            "IP address",
            "I.P. address",
            "ip address"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        report_IP()

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "restart"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        restart()

    if any(pattern in message for pattern in\
        [
            "SSH",
            "reverse"
        ]
        ):

        triggered.append(True)
        engage_command(
            command    = "ssh -R 10000:localhost:22 www.sern.ch",
            background = True
        )

    if any(triggered):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def report_IP(
    contact = None,
    country = True
    ):

    IP = "unknown"

    try:

        data_IP_website = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/json")
        data_IP         = data_IP_website.json()
        IP              = data_IP["ip"]
        country         = data_IP["country"]

    except:

        pass

    text = "IP address: " + IP

    if country:

        text = text + " (" + country + ")"

    print(text)

def restart():

    print("restart! (and I'm in a crazy loop!)")
    import __main__
    os.execv(__main__.__file__, sys.argv)

def report_help():

    print("I can report my IP address, I can restart my script and I can run commands.")

def engage_command(
    command    = None,
    background = False
    ):

    print("engage command: {command}".format(command = command))

    if not background:

        process = subprocess.Popen(
            [command],
            shell      = True,
            executable = "/bin/bash"
        )
        process.wait()
        output, errors = process.communicate()

        return output

    else:

        subprocess.Popen(
            [command],
            shell      = True,
            executable = "/bin/bash"
        )

        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: It seems as if https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  might be a better fit for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Note: the code below is for Python 3.5 or higher.
First, you separate the logic of the parsers from the logic of the code that runs strings through parsers. Let's start with the code for the latter:

```
from typing import List


def run_parsers(message: str, parsers: List[BaseParser]) -> None:
    for parser in parsers:
        parser.parse_message(message)
```

Note: In the latest Python versions, you can annotate your code. The reason why I chose to do this here is to make it clear that this function doesn't care what "type" of parser it gets. It expects a list of `BaseParser` instances(including instances of classes that inherit from `BaseParser`) and then calls the `parse_sting` method of each of them on `message`. This function doesn't care what `parse_message` does.
Next, you want to define an API for your parser objects so that `run_parsers` can use them without knowing how they work.

```
class BaseParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.triggered = False

    def parse_message(self, message: str):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

As you can see `BaseParser` has almost no logic, it just says that whoever inherits from me should define `parse_message`. Also, inheriters get a `triggered` attribute.
Now, let's see the code for one such inheriter.

```
class ImageParser:

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.key_phrases = ('jpg', 'png')

    def parse_message(self, message):
        for phrase in self.key_phrases:
            if phrase in message:
                self.respond()
                self.triggered = True

    def respond(self):
        do_something_here()
```

As long as inheriters follow the "rules" set by the BaseInheriter(i.e. implement a method and have an attribute called `triggered`), `run_parsers` will happily run them.
Note:`ImageParser` sets `triggered` to True and this is how you can determine which parsers took some action.
Finally, let's convert your `main` function to make it work with the above code:

```
def main():
    message = 'how  are you?'
    parsers = [ImageParser(), IPParser()]
    run_parsers(message, parsers)
    if not any([parser.triggered for parser in parsers]):
        show_help()
```

Important tip: make sure you read and use [pep8 guidelines](https://pep8.org/). Object-oriented design complicates the flow of an application and you don't want to further complicate things by coming up with your own code style or conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make more pythonic code while increasing the complexity and quantity of your parse patterns, you really ought to at least check out regular expressions. They are quite intimidating at first, but once you get over the hill a bit they improve your productivity drastically if you are creating code to match patterns on a regular basis. The [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in the python standard library is very straightforward to work with. Below is example code which will match for your ip address request in parse_2.

```
import re
message = 'ip address'
if re.match(r'[iI]\.*[pP]\.*', message):
    report_IP()
```

From your formatting it seems clear that you likely have significant programming experience, but may be new to python. As was previously mentioned, you should check out the [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Python also comes with some awesome features that make doing what you are trying to do a lot easier. If you want to use regex for a lot of patterns and return True if any were matches in a similar fashion to your current program, you might want to do something like this:

```
import re

def print_username(string): print string
def print_password(string): print string
def print_hex(string): print string

triggers = [
    (r'^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$', print_username),
    (r'^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$', print_password),
    (r'^#?([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})$', print_hex)]

def handle_message(message = None):
    if not message: return(False)
    else:
        any_triggered = False
        for trigger in triggers:
            if re.match(trigger[0], message):
                any_triggered = True
                trigger[1](message)
        return(any_triggered)
```

If you want somewhere to quickly practice regex syntax to get the hang of it, [try here](https://regex101.com/).